# How to pass shell commnds as variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have a command that retrieves my most recent git commit hash.

`git rev-parse HEAD`

Is it possible to pass this as an environment variable to a Jenkins pipeline stage?

I've tried to do this,

```
environment {
    CURRENT_COMMIT_HASH=`git rev-parse HEAD`
}
```

but when I echo it in a later stage

```
stage ('Issues Report') {
    steps {
        sh '''
        echo "${CURRENT_COMMIT_HASH}"
        '''
        }   
    }
```

It comes out blank.

```
+ echo
```

Comment: it should return may be try adding the stage for git command then assign it to variable. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

Comment: Why are people so obsessed by multi-line strings in an `sh` step? I've seen them in almost every Jenkins pipeline question with a single `sh` line lately.

Comment: When looking at the accepted answer: Isn't the question about the other way round: _Assigning shell commands' output to a Jenkins environment variable_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
stage ('Stage-Name') {
    environment {
        current_hash = """${sh(
        returnStdout: true,
        script: "git rev-parse HEAD"
        )}"""
    steps {
        sh '''
        echo "My current commit hash is $current_hash"
        '''
        }
      }
```